# Determine in which direction object should rotate

Tags: geometry

I'm writing a simple top-down game with PyGame. The player moves only in in 4 directions, but the character rotates smoothly to the players movement direction.
And here's the problem: how do I determine which direction (clockwise or counter-clockwise) should character rotate to face the same wall as the player? Because when the character spins from 0° to 270° CLOCKWISE, it just looks hilarious.
I need a function which gets current character direction, the direction of player (our target) and outputs 1 for clockwise, -1 for counter-clockwise and 0 if these are already the same.

EDIT: Here is the dirty way I achieved desired effect, *however* I'm still waiting for a more clean, mathematical approach. This one doesn't satisfy me.

```
def angle_clockwise(a,b):
if a!=b:
    c=abs(b-a)
    d=min(c,360-c)
    if d==b-a: k = 1
    else:
        if -1*(b-a)==360-d: k = 1
        else: k = -1
else: k=0
return k
```

Comment: Why don't you use a simple switch/case code for this? Well ... python doesn't have switch/case, so a dict is what you need. If you call the directions N, S, E and W,and then use a `defaultdict` to map a tuple of directions (e.g. (N,E) when character is facing north and target is facing east) to the rotation direction (e.g. (N,E) --> CLOCKWISE).

Comment: With East = 0, North = 1, West = 2, South = 3, then `(current_direction - new_direction + 4) % 4` will give you 0 -> same direction, 1 -> clockwise, 2 -> turn around or 3 -> counter-clockwise. That's not the only way to do it, but it's one possibility...

Comment: It won't work if the character is already in mid-rotation and the player makes a quick backward move

Comment: Well, for mid-turn rotation changes, you probably want to use finer granularity - actual current heading in degrees or something, and desired new heading. But you still want to subtract one from the other and make your decision based on the difference - mapping it to a strictly positive value, or a value between -180 and 180 or such is a simple arithmetic operation.